# Remove selected element from object array

Tags: ios, swift

I have code:

```
struct FilesToDownload {
    var fileInternetUrl: String?
    var fileName: String?
    var savedURL: String?
    var productImageUrl: URL?
    var fileSize: Int
}


var filesToDownload = [FilesToDownload]()

let fileToDelete = "img1000.jpg"
```

How can I delete one, selected file from array (to delete: fileToDelete)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
filesToDownload = filesToDownload.filter { $0.fileName != fileToDelete  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the object that you want to delete and remove it:

```
var filesToDownload = [FilesToDownload]()

let fileToDelete = "img1000.jpg"
// get the index or nil if the array does not contain a file with the given name
let fileToDeleteIndex = filesToDownload.index { $0.fileName == fileToDelete }
// if there is a file -> delete it
if let fileToDeleteIndex = fileToDeleteIndex {
    filesToDownload.remove(at: fileToDeleteIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First find targeted item index and delet. simple!!

```
if let index = filesToDownload.index(where: {$0.fileName == fileToDelete} ) {
    filesToDownload.remove(at: index)
}
```